# Determine if a C string is a valid int in C

Tags: c, string, validation, int

I need to check if a  C string is a valid integer.

I tried both

```
int num=atoi(str);
```

and

```
int res=sscanf(str, "%d", &num);
```

But sending the string `"8 -9  10"` in both of the lines returned simply 8, without indicating the invalidity of this string.

Can anyone suggest an alternative?

Comment: `atoi` does no error checking; its behavior if `str` doesn't contain a representation of an `int` value is undefined.  (Typical implementations return `0`.)  `sscanf` is better, but its behavior is undefined if the value in the string is not representable as an `int`.  Also, your title says you want to check for a valid int, but the body of your question says "valid integer"; they aren't the same thing.  `int` is one of several *integer* types.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have a look at strtol(), it can tell you about invalid parts of the string by pointer return.

And beware of enthusiastic example code.. see the man page for comprehensive error-handling.

Comment: strtol() just sets the pointer to the next "object" in the string. It does not validate anything.

Comment: @g24l If that pointer ends up pointing to NULL, then you know the entire string was valid. If not, not. Tadaa!

Comment: If it is a null terminated string.

Comment: ok, you are right I just noticed that she specified C string.

Comment: Note that `strtol()` returns a `long` result.  If you want to check for a valid `int`, you'll also need to check that the result is in the range `INT_MIN` .. `INT_MAX`.

Comment: The problem is that `strtol` even returns a correct value and set `errno = 0 ` if you input "123dfds" which is not an correct number.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe I'll get flamed for not using `strtol` or similar `libc` functions, but reasoning about this problem is not that hard:

```
#include <stdbool.h>  // if using C99...  for C++ leave this out.
#include <ctype.h>

bool is_valid_int(const char *str)
{
   // Handle negative numbers.
   //
   if (*str == '-')
      ++str;

   // Handle empty string or just "-".
   //
   if (!*str)
      return false;

   // Check for non-digit chars in the rest of the stirng.
   //
   while (*str)
   {
      if (!isdigit(*str))
         return false;
      else
         ++str;
   }

   return true;
}
```

[NB: I might have otherwise done `isdigit(*str++)` instead of the `else` to keep it shorter but my recollection is that the standards say it's possible that `isdigit` is a macro.]

I guess one limitation is that this does not return false if the number in the string won't fit in an integer.  That may or may not matter to you.

Comment: "not that hard", but you had to come back and change it ;)

Comment: @blueshift Point taken, but 1 edit in 5 minutes when typing code into a web form is not that bad to me.  :-)

Comment: In this case I don't know if it's more error-prone to roll your own or to try and get the error-handling for strtol() right.. I'd probably still recommend strtol.

Comment: No, you will not get flamed, and I upvote you, but I think strtol is safer.

Comment: @asveikau: So, this will accept `'-37'` but it will reject `'+42'`?

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this robustly would be to read the int and make sure it's string representation is identical to the input string, for example combining `atoi` and `itoa`:

```
int is_int(char const* p)
{
    return strcmp(itoa(atoi(p)), p) == 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea :). However, this will require trimming leading and trailing spaces as well, in order to make it work.

Comment: Note that this solution is not ANSI compliant.

Comment: Nice solution! Just be careful with frees after.

Answer (score 0):

For checking if string contains a valid number you can use a regular expression. For example for integers use:

[-+]?[0-9]+

and a general case for floating point numbers:

[+-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?

In the case of C++11 regular expression functions are avalaible in  library, e.g. "std::regex_match(.....)" gives the exact match. The code should look like this:

```
#include <regex>
.....
std::string strnumber("-1.234e+01");
float number;
if(regex_match(strnumber,std::regex("[+-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"))
number=std::stof(strnumber);
else
std::cout<<"error, string is not a valid number";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for digging up the topic, but for the sake of completeness and because this thread is the first match when doing a google search...

It is possible to use something like:

```
ret = sscanf(string, "%d%n", &number, &idx);
if (ret == 0 || string[idx] != '\0')
    /* handle the error */
```

the `%n` directive, which seems to be standard C according to the man page, counts the number of characters processed .

**[Edit]** sscanf doesn't seem to provide a way to detect overflows, so the strtoX functions family should be preferred IMHO.