# I couldn't figure out what error is there in my code - segmentation fault core dumped error in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, segmentation-fault, file-handling

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *a[10];  
    int i,j,k;
    float b[10][4][4];
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        char filename[100];
        sprintf(filename,"infile%d.txt",i);
        a[i]=fopen(filename,"r");
    }

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            for (k=0;k<3;k++)
            { 
                fscanf(a[i],"%f",&b[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        printf("\n-----------------%d--------------------",i);
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<3;k++)
            {
                printf("\nb[%d][%d][%d]=%f",i,j,k,b[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have written the above code in C. Which just reads 8 different files and print it in terminal. The file name is infile0, infile1 and son on up to infile7. Though the code runs, it shows segmentation fault core dumped in the terminal. I couldn't figure out why this happens at all. Can some one help me figure out the mistake in the code.

Comment: What if the files are not there? Does it print any of the output?

Comment: Use gdb on the core file to see where the problem is

Comment: Please provide the content of the files

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3):

Compiling with -g and running trough valgrind gives an error line 19 when no files are present.
Maybe you should add

```cpp
if(!a[i])continue;
```

before scanf. (and set some message or default values).

also have a look at [Input validation using scanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228388/input-validation-using-scanf#15228406), as you should check scanf return value.

I hope it helps, this my my first so contribution.

EDIT:
the -g flag is for your compiler, e.g

```sh
gcc -g myfile.c -o myfile
```

then run your binary trough valgrind.
It will tell you any problems with memory: leaks, invalid red/write...

```sh
valgrind ./myfile
```

Don't forget to install valgrind if it is not on your system.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your first answer about the -g ...valgrind thing..How should put that command while compiling and running in terminal

Comment: Sure.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: gcc  filename.c -o filename....I used this command...how should I modify this to get what you said .

Answer (score 1):

A lot of remarks can be done from your code

1) In

> ```
>  void main()
> ```

*main* returns an *int*, not *void*, so must be

> int main()

2) In

> ```
>  FILE *a[10];  
>  ..
>  for(i=0;i<8;i++)
>  {
>     ...
>     a[i]=fopen(filename,"r");
> ```

why do you have an array with 10 entries to only use 8 of them ?, better to have

```
  FILE *a[8];
```

3) `10` (becoming 8) is used a lot of times in your code, if you decide to change the number of elements you will have to change it every where, it is more simple to use a `#define` or `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`

4) In

> ```
> char filename[100];
> sprintf(filename,"infile%d.txt",i);
> ```

you are very generous with the needed size, even your *int* are in 64b and you increase so much the number of entries in *a* (no change to have enough stack nor file description anyway) 20 digits are enough for a positive number, so `char filename[20+10+1];` is enough

5) In

> ```
> float b[10][4][4];
> ...
> for(j=0;j<2;j++)
> {
>    for (k=0;k<3;k++)
> ```

like for 2) there is no reason to use a so large array if you do not use all the entries

6) In

> ```
>  fscanf(a[i],"%f",&b[i][j][k]);
> ```

- you do not check if the corresponding file was open so if `a[i]` is not NULL, probably your segmentation fault comes because a file wasn't open
- you do not detect the end of file nor if the file doesn't contain a valid float, you need to do for instance `if (fscanf(a[i],"%f",&b[i][j][k]) != 1) { ...error management... }`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Unfortunately, nothing works.The error continue to exist

Comment: @user135580 what are you doing when a file is not open ? what the files contain ?