# How to do validation for input? number or alphabet.. C programming

Tags: c, validation, input

```
set1:
printf("Name            : ");
gets (name);
if (isalpha(name)) {printf("\nSorry, input is invalid\n");
goto set1;}
```

this is a piece of my code, and i declared name as char name [30];
but, it says error argument of type *char is incompatible with parameter type int.. and how to validate if we input randomly alphabet and number together (e.g gghjhj88888)?

thank you for helping?

Comment: Post a complete test case. How is `stdNumb` declared? How is it initialized? ...

Comment: You should look into while loops

Comment: I think you need some good book that covers basics. Then you need to start reading the documentation of functions you use: [isalpha](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha)

Comment: i declared as char name [30]; @BLUEPIXY

Comment: `isalpha(name)` isalpha arg is one charactor not pointer to char --> `isalpha(*name)` : meant top char check. and do `#include <ctype.h>`

Comment: this question seems to have an answer.  you should look into it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753346/determine-if-a-c-string-is-a-valid-int-in-c

Comment: @BLUEPIXY okay thanks for the tips, im done with validating if user input number, it's invalid.. but when user inputs mixing number and alphabet, it still doesn't work.. any suggestion?

Comment: I think that it can use isValidName of @VoidPointer is instead of isalpha If you need all of the characters are composed of the alphabet.

Comment: if you want to check the first character isn't alphabetic then do `if (!isalpha(*name))`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY finally, i can complete it :) thank you :) but, i got another validation, how to check if input cannot be more than 6 characters?

dateOfBirth[7]; 

set4:
 printf("Date of Birth (DDMMYYY) : ");
 gets (dateOfBirth);
 if (isalpha(*dateOfBirth)) {printf("\nSorry, input is invalid\n");
 goto set4;}

Comment: @MonicaPanjaitan I wrote the answer column because longer.

Comment: Note that using `gets()` is always a very bad idea.  Use `fgets()` (and deal with the newline) or [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) from POSIX 2008 (and remember to free the space when appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int isdigits(char *s){
    //return value : true if the string is all numbers.
    while(*s)
        if(!isdigit(*s++))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(void){
    char dateOfBirth[7];
    int len;
set4:
    printf("Date of Birth (DDMMYY)  : ");
    //Doesn't accept input more than specified number of characters
    fgets(dateOfBirth, sizeof(dateOfBirth), stdin);
    rewind(stdin);//keyborad buffer flush
    //fflush(stdin);//discard the character exceeding the amount of input
    //How fflush will work for stdin by the processing system (that is undefined)
    //while ('\n' != fgetc(stdin));//skip if over inputted
    len = strlen(dateOfBirth);
    if(dateOfBirth[len-1] == '\n') dateOfBirth[--len] = '\0';//newline drop
    if(len != 6 || !isdigits(dateOfBirth)){
        printf("\nSorry, input is invalid\n");
        goto set4;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) expects an `int` not a `char *` (pointer). You should loop over the string and validate the characters individually:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++){
    if(!isalpha(name[i])){
        /* errors here */
    }
}
```

Also: [goto's are bad!](http://xkcd.com/292/). So is [`gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309746/safe-alternative-to-gets), use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check manpage of [isalpha](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalph).. Its expects `int` as argument.

To know whether user input is valid name or not, create your own function as,

```
/* a-z and A-Z are valid chars */
int isValidName( char *str )
{
  if( str == NULL )
  {
    return 0;
  }

  while( *str )
  {
    if( ! isalpha( *str ) ) 
    {
      return 0;
    }
    str++;
  }
  return 1;
}
```