# Check if a array index is a number or letter?

Tags: c, arrays, numbers, char

I have the following array:

```
array[];
```

I take users input as `"cd SOMETHING"`The "SOMETHING", should be a number.
BUT if the user enters `"cd Hello"` I want to give an error message.  Here is the code that i am using to split the user input:

```
char *arguments[80];
char *split;

split = strtok(userInput," ");

while(split != NULL)
{
    arguments[count++] = split; 
    split = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Now i have the usersInput stored within my arguments array as:

```
arguments[0]; (cd) and arguments[1]; (Hello)
```

Now before I try and pass the arguments to my next function (which needs a number) I need to check if `arguments[1]` is a number or the crap that is currently is.  Then if it is not a number, display an error message, and if it is a number, I can proceed as I would like to.

I tried both `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` but they only work for a single char.

I understand that I could loop through `argument[1]` and split it into individual chars, then loop through those and check each one with isalpha or isdigit but this is somewhat of a hassle, I would like to know if there is a easier way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if a C string is a valid int in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753346/determine-if-a-c-string-is-a-valid-int-in-c)

Comment: "Life's a hassle" - Thanks. Very constructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `strtol` (if the input is supposed to be an integer, anyway):

```
#include <errno.h>
...
char *chk = NULL;
errno = 0;
long val = strtol( arguments[1], &chk, 0 );
if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "%s is not a valid integer string!\n", arguments[1] );
}
else
{
  if ( errno == ERANGE ) 
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "%s cannot be represented as a long\n" );
  }
  else
  {
    // arguments[1] is a valid integer string
    do_something_with( val );
  }
}
```

`strtol` takes the input string and attempts to convert it to the corresponding integer value (result is a `long`).  `chk` will point to the first character in the string that is *not* part of a valid integer string; if this character is not whitespace or 0, then the input was not a properly formed integer string.  The last argument `0` indicates that the input string can be in either hex, decimal, or octal formats, and will be converted appropriately.  If you want to limit valid inputs to decimal format, use `10`.

Comment: THANK YOU so much. This is perfect. And awesome explanation. You were a huge help John Bode!

Comment: @user3602824: Added some sanity checking; it's possible to pass `strtol` a string that's all digits, but doesn't represent a valid `long` value.

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that I could loop through argument[1] and split it into
>   individual chars, then loop through those and check each one with
>   isalpha or isdigit but this is somewhat of a hassle

Hassle or not, it is probably the easiest way to do it in C while allowing long arguments.

```
int looks_like_number(const char *p)
{
    while (*p) {
        if (!isdigit(*p))
            return 0;

        ++p;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Or you can variate and say:

```
while (*p && isdigit(*p)) {
    ++p;
}

return *p == 0;
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I dont mind the hassle, I was just hoping there was an easier way. Thanks for the reply cnicutar

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to split up the string into characters since you can simply iterate over them.

```
while(split != NULL)
{
    arguments[count++] = split;

    while(isdigit(*split)) ++split;
    if(*split) error("non-numeric string!");

    split = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

This increments `split` until a non-digit character is found; if it's not the null character terminating the string then you generate an error.